# Difference between boost::ref and regular references

Tags: c++, boost, reference

What is the difference between `boost::ref(i)` and `& i` ? What are the situations where we cannot use regular references and have to go for `boost::ref` instead? Please include examples if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Boost.Ref Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/ref.html):

> The purpose of
>   boost::reference_wrapper is to
>   contain a reference to an object of
>   type T. It is primarily used to "feed"
>   references to function templates
>   (algorithms) that take their parameter
>   by value.

NB: An important difference between `boost::reference_wrapper` and `std::reference_wrapper` (at least of Boost 1.52) is the ability of `std::reference_wrapper` to perfectly wrap function objects.

This enables code like this:

```
// functor that counts how often it was applied
struct counting_plus {
  counting_plus() : applications(0) {}
  int applications;

  int operator()(const int& x, const int& y) 
  { ++applications; return x + y; }
};

std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3}, y = {1, 2, 3}, result;
counting_plus f;
std::transform(begin(x), end(x), begin(y), 
               std::back_inserter(result), std::ref(f));
std::cout << "counting_plus has been applied " << f.applications 
          << " times." << '\n';
```

Comment: @Venkat Shiva: The situation is "When algorithms need to take their parameter by value" and you do not want to incur the performance penalty of passing an object by value.

Comment: I guess I should read the documentation properly before posting the questions. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

In [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html) for example :

> A new thread is launched by passing an
>   object of a callable type that can be
>   invoked with no parameters to the
>   constructor. The object is then copied
>   into internal storage, and invoked on
>   the newly-created thread of execution.
>   If the object must not (or cannot) be
>   copied, then **boost::ref** can be used to
>   pass in a reference to the function
>   object. In this case, the user of
>   Boost.Thread must ensure that the
>   referred-to object outlives the
>   newly-created thread of execution.

Code from doc :

```
struct callable
{
    void operator()();
};

boost::thread copies_are_safe()
{
    callable x;
    return boost::thread(x);
} // x is destroyed, but the newly-created thread has a copy, so this is OK

boost::thread oops()
{
    callable x;
    return boost::thread(boost::ref(x));
} // x is destroyed, but the newly-created thread still has a reference
  // this leads to undefined behaviour
```